# PHP, jQuery, SQL and HandleBars

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, handlebars.js

I'm trying to take some data from an sql database and pass it through an AJAX request, and then template it with Handlebars. 
The PHP is like:

```
<?php

function isXHR() {
    return isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] );
}


function connect(){
    global $pdo;
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=personal", "root", "");
}

function get_photos( ) {
    global $pdo;

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
        SELECT url, name, smt 
        FROM photos
        LIMIT 50');
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
}
```

The page index is like this:

```
<?php
    require 'functions.php';
    connect();

    if ( isXHR() ) 
    {
        echo json_encode( get_photos() );

        return;
    }
?>

<ul class="photos_list">

    <script id="photo_list_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each this}}
        <li data-smt="{{smt}}">
            <img src="{{url}}" alt="{{name}}"/>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery is like this:

```
var photos = {
    init: function( config ) {
        this.config = config;

        this.setupTemplates();
        this.fetchphotos();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST'
        });


    },


    setupTemplates: function() {
        this.config.photoListTemplate = Handlebars.compile( this.config.photoListTemplate);

    },

    fetchphotos: function() {
        var self = photos;

        $.ajax({

            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(results) {

                console.log(results);
                self.config.photosList.empty();

                if ( results[0] ) {
                    self.config.photosList.append( self.config.photoListTemplate( results) );
                } else {
                    self.config.photosList.append('<li>Nothing returned.</li>');
                }
            }
        });

    }
};

photos.init({
    photoListTemplate: $('#photo_list_template').html(),
    photosList: $('ul.photos_list')
});
```

I don't know how to make it work, but I know i'm doing something wrong. It's the first time when i work with PHP, and ajax request, so i don't really know how to find the mistake.

Comment: No error, just didn't grab anything, but i solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed the php outside the html tags and it worked.